# How to get pip functional again?

Tags: python, pip

I ran into the issue below, while running pip trying to install rpyc. Even if i try to run pip without any arguments it still outputs the same error. Any help would be greatly appriciated, Thanks.

```
volt72@killadelph:~/zone/zone$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2691, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 668, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2691, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2192, in activate
    self.insert_on(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2293, in insert_on
    "with distribute. Found one at %s" % str(self.location))
ValueError: A 0.7-series setuptools cannot be installed with distribute. Found one at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.7.egg
volt72@killadelph:~/zone/zone$
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok after some research I decided to do the following:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.7.egg
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Now pip works with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing distribute

```
sudo pip uninstall distribute
```